# Question about Bridge Pattern implementation

Tags: c++, design-patterns, bridge

Recently, I've made several attempts to understand the Bridge Pattern. Different websites are trying to explain this concept in different ways, but I'm beginning to understand this pattern - decouple abstraction and implementation - allows us to make different kinds of implementations, and additionally, we are able to extend our interface. But I just want to make sure with one thing - based on the example below:

```
#include <iostream>

class Device
{
protected:
    int volume_m{ 0 };
public:
    int getVolume()
    {
        return volume_m;
    }
    void setVolume(int value)
    {
        volume_m = value;
    }
};

class RemoteController
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Device> device_m;
public:
    RemoteController(std::shared_ptr<Device> device) : device_m(device) {}
    void volumeUp()
    {
        device_m->setVolume(device_m->getVolume()+10);
        std::cout << "Volume turned up. Current volume: " << device_m->getVolume() << '\n';
    }
    void volumeDown()
    {
        this->device_m->setVolume(this->device_m->getVolume() - 10);
        std::cout << "Volume turned down. Current volume: " << device_m->getVolume() << '\n';
    }
    
};

class TV : public Device
{

};

class Radio : public Device
{

};


int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Device> tv = std::make_shared<TV>();
    std::shared_ptr<RemoteController> controller = std::make_shared<RemoteController>(tv);
    controller->volumeUp();
    controller->volumeUp();
    controller->volumeUp();
}
```

What if I wanted to make different messages for `TV` and `Radio`? Should I make  virtual methods in `Device` called `volumeUp()` and `volumeDown()` which will be inherited by `Radio` and `TV`? And `RemoteController` would only call these virtual methods?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe that it will be more correct to implement `VolumeUp` `VolumeDown` methods in `Radio` and `TV` objects. Since they can potentially differ for these objects (not step 10 for both).

And I think that it’s better to try not to expose your implementation through getters and setters without much need. More about this [here](https://www.yegor256.com/2014/09/16/getters-and-setters-are-evil.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Should I make virtual methods in `Device` called `volumeUp()` and `volumeDown()` which will be inherited by `Radio` and `TV`? And `RemoteController` would only call these virtual methods?

Yes, in short, The Bridge Pattern uses *delegation*. `RemoteController` delegates to the member functions defined by the `Device` interface. `TV` and `Radio` can override `Device`'s virtual member functions.

The delegation is because The Bridge Pattern relies on *composition*. To understand why it does use composition, let's first see an example that doesn't take advantage of The Bridge Pattern.

### Single Class Hierarchy Example – No Bridge

You have two different types of devices: *TV* and *radio*. Let's assume that you have two different remote controllers: *radio frequency* and *infrared* controllers. Then, you would have four classes in total: `RadioIRController`, `RadioRFController`, `TVIRController`, `TVRFController`. These classes would implement an interface `RemoteController` that specifies the virtual member functions `volumeUp()` and `volumeDown()`, i.e., a single hierarchy (i.e., `RemoteController`).

In this design, if you now wanted to add a new kind of remote controller, for example, an *ultrasonic controller*, you would have to create two additional classes: `RadioUSController` and `TVUSController`. If you, in turn, wanted to add a new kind of device, for example, a *home stereo system*, you would then need to create three additional classes: `HomeStereoIRController`, `HomeStereoRFController` and `HomeStereoUSController`.

As you can see, extending this design is tedious. This is because two orthogonal properties – the kind of device and remote controller – are mixed in a single class hierarchy. This is a strong motivation to switch to The Bridge Pattern.

[image: single-hierarchy]

#### Applying The Bridge Pattern

You split the single hierarchy into two: `Controller` and `Device`. This way, each hierarchy can be extended independently to each other.

[image: bridge]

We've done so by partially switching away from inheritance, embracing composition, and relying on delegation: a `RemoteController` refers to a `Device` and calls the operations on this `Device` object.

Extending this design for additionally supporting a *home stereo system* would only require to create a new class, `HomeStereo`, which inherits from `Device`. Likewise, extending this design for supporting an *ultrasonic controller* would just require the creation of a new class, `USController`, which inherits from `RemoteController`. You can now easily see the difference.